# useOffset=False in config file?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to have

ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)

as default? 
I searched in the example matplotlibrc file but can't see 
anything that could be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, (see [code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/ticker.py#L358)) the  default of `True` is hard-coded.

Please open an issue on the github tracker requesting this feature.