# Change X axis labeling using Pandas/matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I am plotting some columns of a csv using Pandas/Matplotlib. The index column is the time in seconds (which has very high number).
For example:

```
401287629.8
401287630.8
401287631.7
401287632.8
401287633.8
401287634.8
```

I need this to be printed as my xticklabel when i plot. But it is changing the number format as shown below:

[image: fig]

```
plt.figure()
ax = dfPlot.plot()
legend = ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5))
labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
for label in labels:
    label.set_rotation(45)
    label.set_fontsize(10)
```

*I couldn't find a way for the xticklabel to print the exact value rather than shortened version of it.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove relative shift in matplotlib axis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855363/how-to-remove-relative-shift-in-matplotlib-axis)

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially the same problem as [How to remove relative shift in matplotlib axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855363/how-to-remove-relative-shift-in-matplotlib-axis/11858063#11858063)

The solution is to tell the formatter to not use an offset

```
ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
```

Also related:

- [useOffset=False in config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704308/useoffset-false-in-config-file/18706130#18706130)
- https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2400
- https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2401

Answer (score 0):

If it's not rude of me to point out, you're asking for a great deal of precision from a single chart. Your sample data shows a six-second difference over two times that are both over twelve and a half-years long.

You have to cut your cloth to your measure on this one. If you want to keep the years, you can't keep the seconds. If you want to keep the seconds, you can't have the years.